# Android emulator sdcard permisisons not working

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've read many posts about this but nothing seems to solve the problem.

I've created a simple app that basically consists of:

```
    Log.d("RSE", Environment.getExternalStorageState());
    Log.d("RSE", "Readable? " + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Movies").canRead());
```

It always says `mounted` and `Readable? false`

When I try to do anything more, I get a permission denied error.

I've added

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

inside `AndroidManifest.xml` inside the `<manifest>` tag and before the `<application>` tag.

Comment: Worth noting that I've tried other folders inside the sdcard. I can access it all from ADB and can see everything there

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the device, I've personally found `Environment.getExternalStorage*()` to be unreliable in what it points to. In this case, it's probably pointing to the emulated storage which doesn't seem to like I/O. I ended up just using `"/sdcard/Movies/"` which worked far more reliably than `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Movies")` ever did.

Comment: I've tried both /sdcard/Movies and /storage/sdcard/Movies (which is what getExternalStorage*() returns)

Comment: @MichaelBaldry did you make sure to turn usb storage off?

Comment: I can't find that as an option on the emulator

Comment: @MichaelBaldry ahh! That *might* be your problem. The emulator can have problems with reading/writing from the SDCard though it should work. Did you make sure to make an SDCard for the emulator?

Comment: Yes, I can `adb shell` to the emulator and access the sdcard that I created also. Its definitely there and mounted.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why but I recreated the AVD and now its readable.